# 2D Array Unintended Assignment Bug

Tags: python

I want to create a 2D array, like so:

```
grid[y][x]
```

So that there are y amount of rows and x amount of columns.

Below is the way I did it, but I when I tried to assign the (0,0) of the array to contain the value '2', the code assigned the first value of each subarray to '2'.

Why is this happening? How should I pythonically instantiate a 2D array?

```
n = 4 
x=0 
y=0 
grid = [[None]*n]*n 

print grid 

grid[y][x]='Here' 

print grid
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688223/python-list-multiplication-3-makes-3-lists-which-mirror-each-other-when

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959744/python-list-problem or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859301/create-2d-array-in-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745562/appending-to-2d-lists-in-python -- this is a common beginner question.

Comment: Consider `grid = {}; grid[0,0] = 'Here'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `*` you create multiple references, it does not copy the data
so when you modify the first line to

```
[here,none,none,none]
```

you actually change all lines.

solution

```
[[None for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

Edit (from other post) Since only the lists are mutable (can change in place) you can also do

```
[[None]*n for j in range(n)].
```

Each of the rows are then still unique. If the `None` object could be changed in place this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = [[None]*n for i in range(n)]
```